# Dynamic Label Titles

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have an app I am working on where it shows a balance for users that changes. I would like to display these values as they change and the only way I know how to do that would be with a button. But the values often change on a different view controller so I was wondering if I can set labels equal to a variable that update along with those variables.

Since the values change outside of the view controllers with the labels, the normal way I change labels, using a button, does not  apply.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As a general solution, you could achieve this by declaring a *`property observer`* in your view controller, example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var updatedData = "" {
        didSet {
            lblData.text = "Data: \(updatedData)"
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var lblData: UILabel!
}
```

At this point, each time `updatedData` value is edited, the `lblData` label text will be updated.

Note that there is also `willSet` option which is called just before the value is stored, for more information, you could check [Swift Properties Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) - Property Observers.

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot about property observers. Thanks! I’ll give it a try.

Comment: Glad to help... just shoot me a comment if needed :)